# LiveData with data binding not working when minifyEnabled = true in Android Q

Tags: android, proguard, android-livedata, android-10.0

I am using `LiveData` with DataBinding. I used `minifyEnabled=true` in my release config and used  standard proguard rules. Everything works fine in Android 9 and below but however in Android 10(Q) the live data is not calling the observers.

I tried all the different rules based on the answers I found on the Internet, none resolved the issue.

```
# Android data binding
-dontwarn androidx.databinding.**
-keep class androidx.databinding.** { *; }

# Android data binding
-dontwarn com.xxxx.xx.databinding.**
-keep class com.xxxx.xx.databinding.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.xxxx.xx.databinding.** { *; }

-keep class com.xxxx.xx.BindingHelpers.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.xxxx.xx.BindingHelpers.** { *; }
-keep class com.xxxx.xx.DataBinderMapperImpl { *; }


#AndroidX View Model
-keep class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel { *; }
-keepclassmembers class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel { *; }

#AndroidX AttributeSet
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
#AndroidX Annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

#AndroidX Lifecycle
-keepclassmembers enum androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Event {
    <fields>;
}
-keep !interface * implements androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
}
-keep class * implements androidx.lifecycle.GeneratedAdapter {
    <init>(...);
}
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent *;
}


#AndroidX Arch
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.** { *; }
-keep class android.arch.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.arch.**

# ServiceLoader support(coroutines)
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory {}

# Most of volatile fields are updated with AFU and should not be mangled
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
    volatile <fields>;
}
```

When I looked at the [Android samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/72183dfd43bd6311d4a3acae46560ebebc5098c0/LiveDataSample/app/build.gradle#L35), `minifyEnabled=false` is set in build.gradle file.

That fixed my issue.

I wanted to check If anyone else had similar issue and fixed it with minify enabled ?

Is it ok to remove minification?(I know minification reduces APK size by removing un used code, is there anything else that I am missing by removing it?).

Comment: What version of Lifecycle are you using? What is your `compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: We are also having same troubles with observers not being called on API 29 devices. With `minifyEnabled` set to `false` everything works normal. We are using following dependencies: `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0`, `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-rc02`

Comment: Are you using `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx` dependency by any chance? I just managed to solve the problem by updating it to `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0-rc02`

Comment: @ianhanniballake we are using 2.1.0.  By the way with minifyEnabled enabled true. Let me answer my own question.

Comment: Thanks @flyingAssistant! Updating from `rc01` to `rc03` solved the problem for us too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR :

I fixed by keeping all lifecycle classes and members. Just like the data binding rule.

```
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }
```

Longer version;

I enabled minify in debug mode and stepped through Android source code and found that `LiveData` and the `LifecycleBoundObserver` were minified. Because of that, a check to see if the lifecycle observer is active was always returning false.

I do not need to keep all the files to fix the issue I was facing, but I am skeptical that minifying these files might cause some future issues.

Please suggest if there is a better way to fix this.

Comment: This works, however it should be written like `-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }` notice the `-` and the lowercase L in lifecycle. But what also works is updating the lifecycle dependency. I was using `2.2.0-rc01`. I updated it to `2.2.0` instead and it worked (without requiring this proguard rule).

Comment: @Kidus. You are right. I just typed from memory. We may not need this if we use ktx extension for androix fragment.  I didn't test that. I was happy to keep these classes. May be one day.

Comment: This works but it should not be required... Why we need this in a project? 
Make no sense to me, those package should already be kept by Proguard and friends...